# Sum of scaled i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, bernoulli-distribution

Given $X_1,...,X_n\sim Ber(p)$, I am interested in the distribution of the sum $L = \sum_{k=1}^n f_k X_k$ where $f_k$ are positive real numbers, not random. I have seen other posts such as [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270227/what-is-the-cdf-of-the-sum-of-weighted-bernoulli-random-variables)  and [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/568613/how-to-find-the-pmf-of-a-weighted-sum-of-iid-bernoulli-random-variables-with-con), where the last one gives probably the best answer to my question.

I would like to know if there is an explicit way of calculating the distribution of $L$ or, if not, what attempts have been made and why is it so hard to "find" it explicitly.

Comment: It's not hard, really—just time-consuming. You basically enumerate all $2^n$ possible subsets. If there is some non-trivial connection amongst the $f_k$, it may be possible to leverage that in a simplified computation. But in general, I don't think there's any way that's asymptotically faster.

Comment: I see, so an explicit distribution is possible but the number of outcomes is huge for large $n$, so approximations are preferred, or a very efficient algorithm. I thought there might be a nice closed form for it but yes, I do see that there *is* a closed form, its just very big.

Comment: I think it is difficult to go beyond the answer given in the second link in your message. It is a very detailed presentation, even including a possible gaussian approximation considering the CLT. Perhaps if you have more details on how the weights $f_k$ are defined you might find a way to avoid brute force.